# Computer AI opponent in turn based google play game

Tags: android, multiplayer

I am trying to make a four player turn based game.

Now in case their are less than 4 human player I want to start X human player and 4-X  AI player. Is it possible with the google turn based multiplayer https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer

Also in case a human player leaves I want to replace it with the AI player instead of cancelling the game. Does it support this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am implementing this and have it working 90%.  When it is a new turn in my game, I check if the next player is a BOT or HUMAN player.  This is prearranged using a seating algorithm, so that I space out the HUMANs neatly.  i.e. opposite when there are two human players.  When the next player is a BOT, I take a turn, but do not advance the Particpant.  That way it will persist and send an update without passing the turn to the other player.  When the next player is a HUMAN, I do a take Turn and switch to the next player.  The code looks something like this....

if (Players[playerTurn%4]==BOT)  {
  Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.takeTurn(MainActivity.mHelper.getApiClient(),   MainActivity.mMatch.getMatchId(),
                    MainActivity.mTurnData.persist(), myParticipantId).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult result) {
                            processResult(result);
                        }
                    });

```
        state = GameState.Playing;

    } else {

        Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.takeTurn(MainActivity.mHelper.getApiClient(), MainActivity.mMatch.getMatchId(),
                MainActivity.mTurnData.persist(), nextParticipantId).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult>() {

                    public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult result) {
                        processResult(result);
                    }
                });
        state = GameState.multiplayerWait;
```

}

I am not sure how to swap inactive players with another player.  I don't think this is possible unless you run your own server or use something like Parse.